# An error occurred while running D:\fyp sumreen\marketplace\truffle-config.js! Did you forget to `npm install` your project?

Tags: npm, node-modules, ganache

I am running ganache 2.1.2 but facing this error when I add a truffle config file. 
I have already tried to uninstall and then clean and fresh installation of npm node modules and fresh installation of ganache as well.

> An error occurred while running D:\fyp sumreen\marketplace\truffle-config.js! Did you forget to `npm install` your project?

picture of the ganache workplace

[image]